# TypeScript errors with "Could not find a declaration file" for *indirect* dependency

Tags: typescript, bluebird, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I have the following `"noImplicitAny": true` project, with its `dependencies` (not `devDependencies`):

- `wr`

  - `u`

    - `bluebird`

Now, when I try to compile `wr`, tsc errors with:

```
node_modules/u/dist/src/lib/dynamo/Dynamo.d.ts:1:27 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'bluebird'. '/home/ronjouch/work/wr/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/bluebird.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/bluebird` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bluebird';`

1 import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~
```

But:

- `wr` has nothing to do with `bluebird`, I do *not* want `@types/bluebird` in `wr`'s devDeps/deps.
- `u` has `@types/bluebird` in its `devDependencies` and that makes sense because they're required to build `u` but useless to run it, so I do not want to move them to `dependencies` (normal deps / devDeps nuance).

I understand the error (and fix) when it comes to *my* project code, but what am I supposed to do when it happens like here on an *indirect* dependency ? Is there a TS mechanism to cover that case? (Ignore the `noImplicitAny` for dependencies code? Automatically acquire typings?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this file `node_modules/u/dist/src/lib/dynamo/Dynamo.d.ts` that depends on `@types/bluebird` and is getting loaded by `wr` forms part of the public API of `u`, then the [official recommendation](https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81) is to put `@types/bluebird` in the `dependencies` of `u` precisely to avoid this issue.  In principle, `package.json` could support another kind of dependency that `u` could declare on `@types/bluebird` that would cause `@types/bluebird` to be installed when you run `npm install` on `wr` but not when you run `npm install --production`.  But the way I see it, many packages bundle the type declarations in the same package, so if `u` has `bluebird` in `dependencies`, adding `@types/bluebird` to `dependencies` is no worse than if `bluebird` bundled its type declarations, and people shouldn't complain about it.

If `node_modules/u/dist/src/lib/dynamo/Dynamo.d.ts` is *not* part of the public API of `u`, then you should figure out why `wr` is loading it and break the chain.

Comment: It always felt wrong to me to put types packages in `dependencies`, but I have to say that this argument won me over:

"many packages bundle the type declarations in the same package, so if `u` has `bluebird` in dependencies, adding `@types/bluebird` to `dependencies` is no worse than if `bluebird` bundled its type declarations."

So thank you.

Of course, the best solution would be a new type of dependency in `package.json` that propagates to consumers but only applies in development.